# Make Swing component align vertically

Tags: java, swing, components, alignment

Basically I need to get a JLabel component to align to the top of it's parent JPanel.

Here is my code:

```
public static JPanel createBoldLabelPanel(String labelText, Component c, Font font, Color c1){
    c.setFont(new Font(font.getName(), Font.PLAIN, font.getSize()));
    c.setBackground(c1);
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    if(!labelText.isEmpty()){
        jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText);
        label.setFont(new Font(font.getFontName(), Font.BOLD, font.getSize()));
        label.setBackground(c1);
        label.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        jp.add(label);
    }
    jp.add(c);
    jp.setBackground(c1);
    return jp;
}
```

And here is my test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea("Sed ut perspiciatis, unde " +
            "omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem " +
            "aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, " +
            "explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia " +
            "consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, " +
            "qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] " +
            "eius modi tempora inci[di]dunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim " +
            "ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex " +
            "ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, " +
            "quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?");
    jta.setEditable(false);
    jta.setLineWrap(true);
    jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    frame.add(DisplayPanel.createBoldLabelPanel("Test:", jta, new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 14), Color.GRAY));
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

If you run it, what I want should become clear, if it's not already.  Thanks!

[image: As you can see, I need "Test:" moved up]

Comment: So what's the problem?  I don't want to have to run your code and guess what the problem is.

Comment: As I said in the first sentence, "Basically I need to get a JLabel component to align to the top of it's parent JPanel."

Comment: Right, but until you added that picture there was nothing saying what the problem with your code was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also set the aligment property of your text area:

```
jta.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
```

Then both will be aligned to the top within the panel.

Comment: +1, This is right. @MirroredFate, I apologize that the code I provided before didn't align the components to the top. :/

Answer (score 1):

Or change the LayoutManager to BorderLaoyut

```
public static JPanel createBoldLabelPanel(String labelText, Component c, Font font, Color c1) {
    c.setFont(new Font(font.getName(), Font.PLAIN, font.getSize()));
    c.setBackground(c1);
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    if (!labelText.isEmpty()) {
        //jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        jp.setLayout( new BorderLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText);
        label.setFont(new Font(font.getFontName(), Font.BOLD, font.getSize()));
        label.setBackground(c1);
        label.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        jp.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    jp.add(c);
    jp.setBackground(c1);
    return jp;
}
```